# How to set WHERE filter to only show instances of a column where blank in GBQ SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the `WHERE` function to filter out instances where a column of timestamp is empty.

The data set I am working with populates a date in the column `cancelled_datetime` if stock is delivered.

I want to only show data of supplier Walmart where there is no data in the `cancelled_datetime` column. How do I go about doing so?

Below is my script that breaks with the error message:

> {Could not cast literal "" to type TIMESTAMP}

I tried:

```
WHERE supplier_code = "Walmart" 
AND cancelled_datetime <> ""
```

I was expecting to receive a table indicating data from supplier Walmart that does not include a date.

Comment: You are trying to compare a timestamp column with an empty string that can't be cast as a timestamp. Try `AND cancelled_datetime is null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that `cancelled_datetime` column is a [timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type) type, which it will be either a valid timestamp or a NULL value. For what you are looking for, you can use [IS NULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp) filter to get the result you want.

Here is the query:

```
WHERE supplier_code = "Walmart" 
AND cancelled_datetime IS NULL
```